# AS3 Flex dynamically loading images does not allow images' id

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, image

I need to load dynamically a few images (4-6) so that by clicking on particular image user would invoke particular action. Embedding images solves the problem but at the expense of file size. If I load them dynamically, they lose their ID.

```
<comps:ExercisesScroller id="scroller" x="300" y="100"
        ex1="@Embed(source='assets/Exerc_1.png')" 
        ex2="@Embed(source='assets/Exerc_2.png')"/>
```

and so forth this works. But instantiated in CDATA it does not work:

```
import components.ExercisesSCroller;
private var custScroller:ExercisesScroller;
private function init():void {
    custScroller = new ExercisesScroller();
    this.addElement(custScroller);
    custScroller.ex1 = "@Embed(source='assets/Exerc_1.png')";
}
```

I thought it should be quite a trivial task, but so far I can't solve it.

Comment: Thank you Warren for the prompt reply. Embedding image in mxml tag, i.e. using source="@Embed(source='*.png')" is not a problem - event handler works just fine. But I'd like to avoid loading images if user doesn't want/need them. If I try instantiate a custom component (Scroller based) in AS by passing urls of the images to bindable properties of the component, I get runtime error: SWFLoader does not have ID property and there is no default property. Sorry, I don't know how to insert a code to make it more clear. – FT

Comment: FT, click the "edit" link above to see how I added the code to your post, and formatted it.  (You don't have to save the edit changes, it just shows you the Markdown syntax I used to achieve the result.)

Comment: Dear Warren, thank you for the help.
Unfortunately, even with your suggestion, once I click on an image to invoke corresponding function, I still get the runtime error: "ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property id not found on mx.core.FlexLoader and there is no default value".
The code in the component is very simple: event handler function that is called when an image is clicked. A switch inside the function detects the target id: switch(event.target.id){}.
So, when I click the image I get the above error. If the image is embedded, i.e. urls are set in mxml, then everything works fine.

Comment: In that case, you're clearly not showing the important part of the code.  It's not that I believe I'm a genius and thus *obviously* should see the bug from what you've shown, but rather that I observe that no one else has answered.  Try to boil the problem down to a simple single-file example, less than 50 lines, no external components.  Edit your question above to replace what I put in there.  Also, please delete the second and third comments above; they're just noise now.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use @Embed that way.  The last line in your `init()` function should be something like this:

```
custScroller.ex1.source = "http://my.server.com/images/theRealImage.png";
```

This might need some adjustment, since I don't know what the innards of your ExercisesScroller component look like.  You might, for instance, have to just take the URL as a string property, and have code inside the component to apply the change to the internal image.

**EDIT**: By the way, I'm confused about why your code above isn't using a URL to reference the replacement image.  A relative path, like you show, assumes the files are local already, but you said you don't want to download them to the end user's machine until you're sure the user wants them.  Giving a URL like this achieves the result you want: the image isn't downloaded until you change the image's `source` property.

Comment: Thank you Warren for the prompt reply. 
Embedding image in mxml tag, i.e. using source="@Embed(source='*.png')" is not a problem - event handler works just fine.
But I'd like to avoid loading images if user doesn't want/need them. 
If I try instantiate a custom component (Scroller based) in AS by passing urls of the images to bindable properties of the component, I get runtime error: SWFLoader does not have ID property and there is no default property. 
Sorry, I don't know how to insert a code to make it more clear.